# Why I am getting Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin 'http://localhost:56750' has been blocked by CORS?

Tags: .net

Why I am getting Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://mohammad.co.nz/MSTRATAPI/api/Device/Add' from origin 'http://localhost:56750' has been blocked by CORS

I have flutter client ?

here is my code :

```
postData(String deviceId, String name, String age, String mobile,String  lat, String lot, int isOnline)async{  
 Response response;
 var dio = Dio();  
 response = await dio.post('http://mohammad.co.nz/MSTRATAPI/api/Device/Add', 
 data: {
   'device_id': deviceId, 
   'name': name,
   'age':age,
   'phoneNumber':mobile,
   'isOnline':isOnline,
   'lat':lat,
   'long':lot
  },
   options: Options(
      headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    )
 );
```

I have web api:

Here is my code:

```
using Repositories;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITransactionRepository, TransactionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
app.Run();
```

Why I am getting Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://mohammad.co.nz/MSTRATAPI/api/Device/Add' from origin 'http://localhost:56750' has been blocked by CORS ?

Comment: First of all you have different string keys for `AddPolicy` and `UseCors`. I would assume that can be a reason.

Comment: Secondary, is `api/Device/Add` available for anonymous users or does it require authorization?  If latter is true - AFAIK authorized endpoints does not support allowing any origin.

Comment: it allow anonymous